# Google Drive API syncing randomly

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I have set up a [Change Subscription](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/events#add_a_change_subscription) to a Drive file, this is the way it is set:

```
public SyncChangeListener(Context context) {
    apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    apiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) { ... }

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) { ... }

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Query query = new Query.Builder().addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "Sync.bak")).build();
    Drive.DriveApi.query(apiClient, query).setResultCallback(querycallback);
}

final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult> querycallback = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            Log.i("SyncChangeListener", "Status NOT SUCCESS");
            return;
        }

        if (result.getMetadataBuffer().getCount() > 0) {
            DriveResource dr = result.getMetadataBuffer().get(0).getDriveId().asDriveResource();
            dr.addChangeSubscription(apiClient);
        }

        result.getMetadataBuffer().release();
    }
};
```

I have also set up the `DriveEventService` extended class

```
public class SyncChangeEventService extends DriveEventService {

    @Override
    public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And I have set it in the manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".sync.SyncChangeEventService"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.drive.events.HANDLE_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

The problem is that the change event is randomly getting fired. I'm testing this app on two different devices. When one device makes changes to the synced file, the other device *sometimes* gets the change event, but more than often it doesn't, or it does with huge delay.

So, the change subscription is working, but something is wrong because syncing is not guaranteed. I don't know where the problem is, or even if there's one. Where should I look to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check these links:

- [Introducing the Google Drive Android API](https://developers.googleblog.com/2014/01/introducing-google-drive-android-api.html)
- [Google Drive Android API](http://www.androiddocs.com/google/play-services/drive.html)

Per links given above, Google Drive Android API temporarily uses a local data store in case the device is not connected to a network and will automatically and transparently be stored in the Google Drive cloud by Android’s sync scheduler when connectivity is available.

Also, user files are automatically synced between different devices (**provided the app has the same namespace and is signed with the same key**).

Comment: I'm testing on two different devices, the first with debug key, the second with release key. This means they have not only different apk signing keys, but also they refer to different google api keys. Still it is partially working as the main post says. But I'll be empirical till the end and I'll test with the same apk on both devices.

Comment: I have just tried. It works the same way as before. The only viable way to make it always work is to occasionally do a `Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(mGoogleApiClient)`. But I really hate this for two reasons: 1) What is the purpose of setting a ChangeSubscription if I still have to force a sync? Why doesn't it just work as expected from Google API Docs? 2) Doing an occasional sync request causes a wakelock on the device. It causes a slight battery drain which I absolutely want to avoid.